# NotificationCenter does not work between two views

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple project with notification center
So the idea is to have two view controllers as shown on the picture

[image: two ViewControllers is Main.Storyboard]

When I click on the button `SelectionVC` gets loaded and if I click
on one of the buttons on `SelectionVC` I wanna create notification and
go back to first view controller and change the label text, but so far I can not sort it out.

ViewController code

```
import UIKit

let mainNotificationName = Notification.Name("mainNotification")
let catalogueNotificationName = 
Notification.Name("catalogueNotification")

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: mainNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        print(notification)
        self.labelText.text = "Main Notification"
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: catalogueNotificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        print(notification)
        self.labelText.text = "Catalogue Notification"
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectionVC") as! SelectionVC

    present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

SelectionVC code

```
import UIKit

class SelectionVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func mainButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: mainNotificationName, object: nil)

    let targetVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func catalogueButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: catalogueNotificationName, object: nil)

    let targetVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}   
}
```

Can you please help me sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these actions :

```
@IBAction func mainButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: mainNotificationName, object: nil)

    let targetVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func catalogueButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: catalogueNotificationName, object: nil)

    let targetVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

To :

```
@IBAction func mainButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: mainNotificationName, object: nil)

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func catalogueButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: catalogueNotificationName, object: nil)

   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And add notification observer in `viewDidLoad()` not in `viewWillAppear()`. And change text on Main thread (just use `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`).